# How to use JSON API without document

Tags: json, jelastic

This might be a weird question but I am open for all the suggestions.

The background is I want to use script to automatically deploy/remove docker container on Jelastic, but unfortunately this part is not well documented in Jelastic official API document. Jelastic provided me a piece of sample code demonstrated how to use bash to create a new environment with a new docker container but it is not enough, I still don't know how to create/remove docker container by looking at the sample code.

Since Jelastic is using standard JSON API, I am wondering is there any tool which can automatically retrieve/detect that the parameters I can use with Jelastic JSON API?

If you were me, how would you get over this if there is no document as reference?

I am keen to use Jelastic, but this issue stopped me from onboarding, many thanks.

J.

Answer (score 0):

All the parameters that can be used with Jelastic JSON API are specified at http://docs.jelastic.com/api/ page.

To use JSON API without document I suggests to you check the **Postman** API tool https://www.getpostman.com/. This application allows you to see all the sent/received data and allows you to passes JSON values without any document or any additional actions.

[image]

Simplest scenario for beginners: Go to [API docs](http://docs.jelastic.com/api/), section Users>Authorization, using **Signin** method you should to obtain the **session** value, that is necessary almost for all further actions. Then you need to obtain information about environment, section Environment>Environment, at first you should to executes **GetEnvs** method, then using the application identifier of the environment that was obtained from the previous command you should to executes **GetEnvInfo** method. As a results of the described scenario you will get all parameters and values that can be used with Jelastic JSON API for certain type of the environment.